# How to detect onclick event only smart phone and tablet using javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, touchscreen

How to detect `onclick` event only smart phone and tablet using `javascript` ?

https://jsfiddle.net/d87zjbLp/3/

i use this code, but i want to call function `myFunction()` only on smart phone and tablet only (not on pc and notebook)

How can i do that ?

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("test");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

https://jsfiddle.net/0ozss4q4/1/

Frist check if is a mobile or a tablet

```
function isMobileOrTablet() {
 if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
 ) {
  return true;
 }else {
  return false;
 }
}
```

Then create a main function that will only run if is a mobile or tablet

```
function onlyMobileAndTablet(callback) {
 if(isMobileOrTablet()) {
  return callback && callback()
 }
}
```

Then just call this function where you want

```
onlyMobileAndTablet(function() {
 console.log('only mobile or tablet');
});
```

Or you can do like this.

```
function isMobileOrTablet(callback) {
     if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
      || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
      || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
      || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
      || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
      || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
      || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
     ) {
      return callback && callback(true);
     }else {
      return callback && callback(false);
     }
    }
```

Then call the function and check the returned value

```
isMobileOrTablet(function(res) {
 if (res) {
  // This is mobile/tablet
 } else {
  // this is not a mobile/tablet
 }
});
```

Comment: Note: I edit the answer as I was missing a } at the end of the function isMobileOrTablet

Answer (score 0):

You should just use the "on touchstart" attribute.

Maybe there is a better event for your will, like touchend, or maybe touchenter;

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml